# CUBIC custom 20.04 ISO fails testing phase

Tags: server, 20.04

I need to customize an install of Ubuntu 20.04 Server to include a few packages since my bare metal server is 'offline'. I downloaded 20.04.5 live ISO, went through the default CUBIC steps and it fails 'test'. I then downloaded 20.04.1 legacy server, walked through the steps of CUBIC and it too fails testing. The error I receive is

**"Your installation CD-ROM couldn't be mounted. This probably means that the CD-ROM was not in the drive. If so you can insert it and try again. Retry mounting the CD-ROM?"**

I really need to complete this task as soon as possible, I've already spent hours troubleshooting.

Thank you for your time and expertise,
Steve

Comment: Why not use the 20.04.6 ISO?  (*officially not released; so it's still a RC (*release candidate*), but it's late and the only issue with it was a nvidia module that I suspect you won't miss*).   I have no experience with Cubic, but an alternative is an untouched *live* system written using persistence etc (so you have an additional area on thumb-drive) & you run a script to install the packages from the persistence area post-install...

Comment: in the CHROOT step of the process with cubic I run the upgrade cmd and it upgrades to the 20.04.6 version of Ubuntu server. the difference is the installer is the legacy installer system

Comment: FYI: 20.04.6 has been released; https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2023-March/000287.html so you're using an *outdated* ISO now officially.